# Is it possible to not animate the exit animation when using a Shared Element Transition?

Tags: android, android-animation, shared-element-transition

I just want the enter animation but want the default exit activity animation when exiting. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dunno if this is considered hacky but here is the solution that I found. The transition doesn't happen if I call `finish()` and only happens inside `onBackPressed()`. So,

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    finish();
}
```